# Clear PIN Cache smartcard

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, smartcard

in .net I'm doing web requests to a web service on ssl. For cryptography I have to use a certicicate from a USB secure card device protected by a PIN code

My code for doing web request ...

```
Dim lRequest As HttpWebRequest
lRequest = WebRequest.Create(lAddress)
lRequest.Method = "POST"
lRequest.KeepAlive = True
lRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11
lRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
lRequest.ContentLength = lRequestContent.Length
lRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "")
lRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(gcert)
```

and with this before in order to make the call working ...

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate)

Public Function ValidateServerCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

and where gcert is the certificate from the windows personal store ...

```
Public gcert As X509Certificate2

Dim store As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
...
```

All of this works fine : when I send my webRequest I'm prompted for a PIN and then I receive the response from web service.
And if I'm doing other calls I'm not prompted again for the PIN but all calls work perfectly.

**But now my problem is :** I want to clear the PIN cache in order to be prompted again for the PIN at each call or if I tell my program to do it (for example a "disconnect" button or a timeout after 10mn for example)
I can't succeed to reset the PIN in order to be prompted again at next call...

After some reseach i tried this :

```
<DllImport("schannel.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Function SslEmptyCache(ByVal pszTargetName As IntPtr, ByVal dwFlags As UInt32) As Boolean
End Function

Public Function SslEmptyCache() As Boolean
    WriteTrace("> SslEmptyCache")

    Try

        Return SslEmptyCache(IntPtr.Zero, 0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteTrace("Echec SslEmptyCache")
    End Try

    Return False

End Function
```

and this

```
ClearPINCache(gcert.PrivateKey)


Public Function ClearPINCache(ByVal key As RSACryptoServiceProvider) As Boolean

    Const PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN As UInt32 = 32
    Const PP_SIGNATURE_PIN As UInt32 = 33
    Dim bretval As Boolean = False

    Dim hProv As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    If (CryptAcquireContext(hProv, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, CUInt(key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType), 0)) Then
        If ((CryptSetProvParam(hProv, PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN, Nothing, 0) = True) And (CryptSetProvParam(hProv, PP_SIGNATURE_PIN, Nothing, 0) = True)) Then
            bretval = True
        End If
    End If

    If (hProv <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0)
        hProv = IntPtr.Zero
    End If

    Return bretval

End Function
```

The clearPINCahe function seems doing nothing

The SslEmptyCache function clears something but after the next call I'm not prompted again for the PIN but I get this error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
the same as if I didn't provide the clientCertificate in the call

Anybody has an idea about what i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: It might be that you provide your users with a false sense of security when you ask for a new PIN. The smart card has already logged you in, and apparently it does not require a PIN for transactions. So anybody with access to the card interface can still use it to authenticate him/herself to your webservice. With some luck you can tell the card to use the PIN for each transaction or signature generation, and .NET hopefully will pick that up.

Comment: Have same problem, do you remember how you solved it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't solve it really. the only way I found is to close my app and open another one

Answer (score -1):

If your using a webpage and not a windows form, maybe you can stop the page from caching by using the page headers?

something like

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Comment: It's a windows form. I also tried to use HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore on HttpRequestCachePolicy of my request, but nothing change.